# Move Min, Max buttons in Google Chrome to tab bar when maximized?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, menu-bar

Is anyone aware of a trick to move min, max buttons in Google Chrome tab bar, when maximized? If not, there's a blank row to hold those buttons, which is a waste of room...BTW this will push down/up the webpage each time the mouse enters the menu area...

See the image below:
[image]

[Here's a better description of the issue](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16738205/web-pages-pushed-down-in-os-x-full-screen-mode?hl=en)

> **Web pages pushed down in OS X full screen mode**
>
> In the full-screen mode in OS X, if you move your cursor to the top of
> tab switcher, the mac menu appears and chrome's toolbar and web page
> content displayed is pushed down.
>
> The expected behavior is that the toolbar overlays the web page, the
> page itself does not move (like in Safari).  This actually worked in
> older Chrome versions.
>
> If you graze the menu bar (top of screen), it is jarring how it pushes
> the content down instead of just doing an overlay.

Who knows if is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

The min/max buttons belong to the window itself, the rest is the window content.

Comment: Hello, maybe there's a workaround? See my edits. BTW other apps (Safari manage this in a much better way)

Comment: Riccardo, RE: "Hello, maybe there's a workaround? " -- No and the issue is **Google Chrome** is not conforming to the current standards set by **Apple** and you should address this issue with the developer of **Google Chrome**.

Comment: Actually, now I've got home & looked at this on a computer rather than my phone - mine doesn't do that. The traffic lights sit to the left of the tab bar, not separately. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/RugWN.png

Comment: On mine, the traffic light sit to the left of the tab bar only when the window is not in full screen